# Issue retrieving my documents from storage - hibernate, springboot, java, sql application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf, storage

I have a java application that allows users to upload documents. The uploaded docs are saved on a network in a specific "client-files" folder and logged in the SQL database in a document storage table. Adding them the the specific file on the network is working accurately, but when I click to download (aka view) the file from the applicataion in the browser, it is returning a 404 error. The url is accurate, and I am not sure where to start with trouble shooting this issue. Any idea, what I should be looking at as to why this isn't working? Clearly the paths are set up correctly since I can download from the app to the storage file. Just not sure what is blocking it from sending it back. Can it be something on the server side?

Also, not sure what code you'd need to know to look at this. This is the download button....

```html
<td>
    <span>
     <span th:text="${doc.storage}"></span>
     <a th:href="@{|/client-files/${client.principleName+' '+client.id+'/'+doc.storage}|}"><i class="fa fa-download"/></a>
    </span>
</td>
```

It doesn't look like the code base has a controller for the viewing aspect. It appears it is just appending the link and supposed to access the folder/files via calling the link?

```html
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/client-files/**").addResourceLocations("file:client-files/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/client-files/**").addResourceLocations("file:carrier-files/");
}
```

```html
@Controller
public class DocumentsController {
    @Autowired
    ClientRepository clientRepository;
    @Autowired
    LicenseRepository licenseRepository;
    @Autowired
    DocumentRepository documentRepository;
    @Autowired
    StorageService storageService;
    @Autowired
    DocumentService documentService;
    @Autowired
    InsuranceRepository insuranceRepository;
    @Autowired
    CarrierAppointmentRepository carrierAppointmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/documents/client/{id}")
    public String manageDocuments(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Client client){
        Document newDocument=new Document();
        License newLicense=new License();
        Insurance newInsurance=new Insurance();

        model.addAttribute("insurances",insuranceRepository.findByClient(client));
        model.addAttribute("newDocument",newDocument);
        model.addAttribute("newLicense",newLicense);
        model.addAttribute("newInsurance",newInsurance);
        model.addAttribute("licenses",licenseRepository.findByClient(client));
        model.addAttribute("docs",documentRepository.findByClient(client));
        model.addAttribute("client",client);

        return "documents";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save/document")
    public String addDoc(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="newDocument") Document newDocument, @RequestParam("document") MultipartFile file){
        Document doc=documentRepository.save(newDocument);
        doc.setStorage(storageService.store(file,newDocument.getClient()));
        documentRepository.save(doc);
        documentService.markDocuments(newDocument.getClient(),newDocument.getType());

        return  "redirect:/documents/client/"+newDocument.getClient().getId();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/doc/{id}")
    public String deleteDoc(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Document doc, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (doc.getClient()!=null) {
            String type = doc.getType();
            storageService.delete(doc.getStorage(),doc.getClient());
            documentRepository.delete(doc);
            documentService.markDocuments(doc.getClient(), type);
            return "redirect:/documents/client/" + doc.getClient().getId();
        }else{
            String username= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
            Role role=roleRepository.findByUsernameContainingIgnoreCaseAndActive(username,true);
            if (!role.getIsCarrierAdmin()){
                return "redirect:/accessDenied";
            }

            storageService.delete(doc.getStorage(),doc.getCarrierAppointment());
            documentRepository.delete(doc);
            return "redirect:/carrierAppointment/details/" + doc.getCarrierAppointment().getId();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save/insurance")
    public String addInsuranceDoc(@ModelAttribute(value="newInsurance")Insurance newInsurance,@RequestParam("insurance-file") MultipartFile file){
        Insurance insurance = insuranceRepository.save(newInsurance);
        insurance.setProof(storageService.store(file,newInsurance.getClient()));
        insuranceRepository.save(insurance);
        documentService.markInsurance(newInsurance.getClient());
        return  "redirect:/documents/client/"+newInsurance.getClient().getId();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/insurance/{id}")
    public String deleteInsurance(Model model,@PathVariable("id")Insurance insurance){
        storageService.delete(insurance.getProof(),insurance.getClient());
        documentService.markInsurance(insurance.getClient());
        insuranceRepository.delete(insurance);
        return "redirect:/documents/client/"+insurance.getClient().getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the controller that is handling the images request?

Comment: try to access the document url in browser directory in new tab(not from the app)

Comment: @AlainCruz, it doesn't look like there is a controller/mapping for the action. Almost looks like it's just trying to append the file path to the end of the url and therefore access the file that way. Added more code for you to look at.

Comment: @Alien , I can access the file in the web browser inside the server, the url shows as the url inside the app, so not sure why it's sending a 404 page and not rendering the actual file.

Comment: The images are on Server right? If so, you need a controller that will fetch then for you, other wise you would try to fetch images that are on your application. Or are they on your application?

Comment: Ended up restarting the server and it is now working correctly. Must be something on the Tomcat side.